# forkOS seems to fail reserving the thread's local storage

Tags: multithreading, opengl, haskell, concurrency, ghc

I'm getting an error when using various GL operations in a fork (they work fine on the main thread). For instance with `createProgram` I'm getting:

> user error (unknown OpenGL extension entry glCreateProgram, check for OpenGL 3.1)

I'm calling it after I've initialized my context (4.3 core), of course.
The issue is that I'm getting this error while using `forkOS`, yet it still fails (as if I'm in a TLS that doesn't know of the GL context).

What's going on?

```
module Main where
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    getArgsAndInitialize
    initialDisplayMode $= [RGBMode, DoubleBuffered] 
    initialContextVersion $= (4,3)
    initialContextProfile $= [CoreProfile]
    initialContextFlags $= [DebugContext, ForwardCompatibleContext]
    createWindow "GL Window"

    createProgram -- Works
    forkOS $ void createProgram -- Fails (user error)

    displayCallback $= do
        clearColor $= Color4 0.2 0.2 1 1
        clear [ColorBuffer]
        flush >> swapBuffers

    mainLoop
```

Comment: Seems like the GL context is still bound to the (OS) thread you originally created it with.

Comment: @derhass Yes, it is bound to it. Which is why I expect `forkOS` to be able to successfully make those calls, but it fails, as you can see.

Comment: Can you post a short sample program that demonstrates this issue?  It's difficult to debug without seeing what you're doing (although I suspect you're not performing *all* the OpenGL calls within a single `forkOS` thread).

Comment: @JohnL Posted, and thank you. If I may ask, what do you mean *all* OpenGL calls? when I `forkOS` would I need to make additional ones besides the one I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL contexts are bound to a thread. Essentially they are a TLS structure. `forkOS` will not automagically "carry over" your OpenGL context binding for you. The idea of `forkOS` is that Haskell operations bound through it are kept within the same thread as the operating system sees it. forkIO may shuffle operations between threads by means of Haskells own scheduler, which would just make keeping the TLS association of FFI-called libraries and APIs a nightmare.

When GLUT `createWindow` executes, it creates both a window *and* an OpenGL context and bind that to the calling thread.

So you have to options: Either you rebind the OpenGL context to that other thread. Or you create another context, install a namespace sharing toward the first one, and bind that to the other thread.

Comment: I figured that if I'm in the same thread, I would have the same TLS (therefore carry over the OpenGL context). How come it is not the case?

Comment: `forkOS` creates a new thread. Hence `createProgram` is executed in a different thread than the OpenGL context was created in (and is bound to). And without a OpenGL context, OpenGL calls will fail. http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=forkOS: `Like forkIO, this sparks off a new thread to run the IO computation passed as the first argument, and returns the ThreadId of the newly created thread.`

Comment: Oh, so basically `forkIO` may be on the same OS thread or a new one, and may shuffle; and in contrast `forkOS` will always be in a new single thread? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @MasterMastic: Yes. That's essentially the gist of it.